# How can I correct this basic standard deviation code on Dev-C++ 5.11?

Tags: dev-c++

This is some sample code (don't mind the numbers):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int student_counter;
    float s_deviation;
    student_counter = 7;
    s_deviation = (1/student_counter)*sqrt(((student_counter*276)-1764)/student_counter-1);
    printf("%f ",s_deviation);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting `0.000000` as output. How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect here but change the `student_counter` to float.
`float student_counter` the value should then be `student_counter = 7.0`.

Actually you had kept it `int` so all the calculation was in int and it had dropped the fractional part. That's why you had 0 as an output.

If you want to keep it `int` as it should logically be, then the calculation should be in floats:

`s_deviation = (1.0/student_counter)*sqrt(((student_counter*276.0)-1764.0)/student_counter-1.0);`
There should be 1 float value atleast in the calculation to get a float result in C/C++.